# Strange lifetime error when iterating over a BTreeSet asynchronously

Tags: generics, rust, async-await, lifetime

I want the async block in the following code to implement `Send` ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4d4ad7340b81b6898c39c0a81163baf8)):

```rust
use std::collections::BTreeSet;
use std::future::ready;

pub fn test<T: Sync>(set: &BTreeSet<T>) -> impl Send + '_ {
    async move {
        for _ in set {
            ready(()).await;
        }
    }
}
```

But it gives the following error:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0311]: the parameter type `T` may not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:4:44
  |
4 | pub fn test<T: Sync>(set: &BTreeSet<T>) -> impl Send + '_ {
  |             --                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...so that the type `T` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  |             |
  |             help: consider adding an explicit lifetime bound...: `T: 'a +`

error: aborting due to previous error

error: could not compile `playground`

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

I don't understand the error at all. Adding a lifetime bound does not solve the problem ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7650454ee10e92dc06a234f0b8a03ea7)), unless the added lifetime bound is `'static` ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1bb0468f3aeb9f63673aa64328fcf048)).

I tried replacing `BTreeSet` with `Vec`, `VecDeque`, `LinkedList`, `HashSet`, `BinaryHeap`. All compiled without error. What is so special about `BTreeSet`?

---

**Update**: This seems to be fixed in Rust 1.66.0. The code now compiles without error.

I still don't know the reason of this error and how it was fixed.

Comment: Weird...  Wonder if its worth creating a Rust-lang issue for. Even if there is a reason for it, the error message is unhelpful.

Comment: I agree, that should be looked at. It is worth noting that the iterator does not even have to be used to cause this behaviour - [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3ca35174e4e50a85f804b86ab35ae221).

Comment: I don't have much of an idea myself, but i noticed that `BTreeSet` implementation of `IntoIterator` creates a new `IntoIter {iter: self.map.into_iter() }` structure (https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/collections/btree/set.rs.html#1077) , unlike implementations for `Vec`, `BinaryHeap`, etc. I don't fully understand it yet, but something about referencing `self.map` might be here at play.

Comment: @somnium `self.map` is used because `BTreeSet<T>` is a wrapped `BTreeMap<T, ()>`. `BTreeMap` has the same problem, for both generic keys ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3b8f9678cf8b59fa62c16efe33ee17e3)) and generic values ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=40e0ad23060a36fead3bc6eea95c94fe)).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the error is a bug in Rust -- `async` functions are fairly new and it seems that there are a number of issues with odd or incorrect compiler errors, particularly with generics.  I think this may be [issue #71058](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/71058) or maybe [issue #64552](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/64552).

I find that often lifetime errors like this, just mean the compiler is saying "Help! I'm confused."

Here's an example of a gratuitous change, which I think is functionally the same:

```
use std::collections::BTreeSet;
use std::future::ready;

type ItemType = dyn Sync;

pub fn test<ItemType>(set: &BTreeSet<ItemType>) -> impl Send + '_ {
    async move {
        for _ in set {
            ready(()).await;
        }
    }
}
```

which produces an error which I think is closer to what is tripping up the compiler (but still incorrect) [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4d4ad7340b81b6898c39c0a81163baf8):

```
error: future cannot be sent between threads safely
 --> src/lib.rs:6:52
  |
6 | pub fn test<ItemType>(set: &BTreeSet<ItemType>) -> impl Send + '_ {
  |                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ future created by async block is not `Send`
  |
note: captured value is not `Send`
 --> src/lib.rs:8:18
  |
8 |         for _ in set {
  |                  ^^^ has type `&BTreeSet<ItemType>` which is not `Send`
help: consider restricting type parameter `ItemType`
  |
6 | pub fn test<ItemType: std::marker::Sync>(set: &BTreeSet<ItemType>) -> impl Send + '_ {
  |                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The above Rust error says that the future is not `Send` which would be the case if the async closure captured a data structure that did not support `Send`. In this case, it captures BTreeSet which *does* support [Send](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/struct.BTreeSet.html#impl-Send).
Why this happens with `BTreeSet` and not `Vec` or one of the other data structures you mention is likely some tiny difference in the syntax of its implementation that is tripping up the compiler.

You created a nice minimal example, so not sure what you are trying to accomplish.  Here's a workaround that might help:

```
use std::collections::BTreeSet;
use std::future::ready;
use std::vec::Vec;
use futures::future::join_all;

pub async fn test<T: Sync>(set: &BTreeSet<T>) -> impl Send + '_ {
    let mut future_list = Vec::new();
    for _ in set {
        let new_future = async move {
            ready(()).await;
        };
        future_list.push(new_future);
    };
    join_all(future_list).await
}
```

Comment: It could well be a compiler bug, but the question specifically asks why it happens with `BTreeSet`, but not with `Vec` or `HashSet`. I obviously don't speak for the OP but an answer that doesn't at least attempt to cover that is IMHO incomplete.

Comment: Yes, it is incomplete.  I did actually look into that, but when I discovered many bug reports in this area, I decided not to look into it further myself.  I left an answer to be helpful, and am not bothered if it does not merit a bounty.  I attempted to illustrate how compiler bugs can be triggered by somewhat arbitrary syntax differences, and also supply a workaround.